# Using ListOfArrayDataSource in subreports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a two Jaser Reports:

- `MasterReport.jrxml`
- `SubReport.jrxml`

I have a `ListOfArrayDataSouce` which I pass to the `MasterReport`, as a parameter. In the `SubReport` element, I chose `DataSourceExpression`, as the afformentioned parameter.

My question is, how to use the passed values in the subreport?

E.g. I would like to create a line chart element; how do i reference the passed data?

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: Are you using this datasource in MasterReport?

Comment: No, I'm using a different one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create fields in the subreport that correspond to the names given to the constructor. I'll explain with a bit of code:

```java
String[] rec1 = {"value11", "value12"};
String[] rec2 = {"value21", "value22"};
String[] rec3 = {"value31", "value32"};

List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(rec1);
list.add(rec2);
list.add(rec3);

JRDataSource subinformeDatasource = new ListOfArrayDataSource(
    list,
    new String[]{"field1", "field2"});
```

Given the code above, the subreport must contain both fields `field1` and `field2`. Then you must specify as the TextField's Expression (in the detail section of the subreport) either of `$F{field1}` or `$F{field2}`.